# Foreign key column which allows null values

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I need to represent a form, called E-Report, where users will add data.

Every E-`Report` will have a `QAP` and every `QAP` will have two or more `Defects`.

These defects will show here, in this table:

[image]

At first time, this table will have two defects and user could add more defects from QAP, or insert new ones if he/she think that it is necessary.

User will check or not `CRS`, `CRF`, `MA` and `MI` columns and I will save these data on `EReportDefect` table.

By the way, `QAP` and `Defect` data will be in a **web service**, I need to download it to my Android device. I can't modify these two tables adding more data.

To represent that I have designed this Visio:

[image]

Because I can't add data to `Defect` table I've created `EReportDefect` table to store `CRS`, `CRF`, `MA` and `MI` user data and to store new Defects created by user.

To represent a new `Defect` added by user, I've set `EReportDefect.defectId` as NULL and `EReportDefect.description` to store new Defect description.

These new defects will have no value on `EReportDefect.defectId` and a value on `EReportDefect.description`.

Is this correct? Could I have a Foreign key column with a NULL value? Do you know a better approach?

Comment: I didn't really read all of that but allowing a foreign key to be null isn't strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nullable foreign keys are perfectly acceptable.

Consider the following case, a messages table which is designed to be responded to by a user.

```
CREATE TABLE Messages 
(
  MessageId int,
  MessageText varchar(256),
  AnsweredByUserId int
)
```

Now, when the initial unanswered message is first created, AnsweredByUserId will be NULL.  That's perfectly fine.  The message hasn't been answered, so we wouldn't expect to find a value in there.

When someone does answer the message, we want to put their UserId into AnsweredByUserId, and we want to enforce referential constraints when that happens ( e.g. we want to ensure that the UserId we insert actually exists in our Users table ).

In conclusion, fine to have a NULLABLE foreign key in the right circumstances.